# Workarounds if I have SF projects with different runtimes

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Currently I have VS2015 SF projects. I downloaded VS2017 and try building/experimenting SF project with newer runtimes. Is this doable? My initial try did not seem to work.

Comment: What issues do you get? You can't have multiple versions of the sdk installed side by side.

Comment: The package.json uses a different version of the SF than my run-time. My runtime is newer version. I know it did not work before (if they are not the same version) but I am wondering if the newer runtime versions can be backward compatible with the versions that the app will be using.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime is always backwards-compatible with older SF NuGet package, so just make sure your NuGet package versions are at or below the runtime that you are deploying to.

Comment: In NuGet there is a strict version dependency, for example https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data/2.6.210 depends on Microsoft.ServiceFabric (= 5.6.210), therefore if a library depends on Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data 2.5.x I can't use it anymore. Is this done on purpose?

Comment: When I load the project it will ask me "...*.sfproj must be upgraded in order to be loaded...". If I click 'No', it will not load project. How can I load the project without upgrading?